# Adding search icon to @Html.TextBox -z-index

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc

[image]

How can I add a search icon to a text type input box? For example I want to have 'fa fa-search' in a input, something like this:

the below code works fine but if I try to do something in asp.net mvc it does not work.

**html:**

```
<div class="col-xs-6">
  <div class="right-inner-addon">
    <i class="icon-search"></i>
    <input type="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" />
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.left-inner-addon {
    position: relative;
}

    .left-inner-addon input {
        padding-left: 30px;
    }

    .left-inner-addon i {
        position: absolute;
        padding: 10px 12px;
        pointer-events: none;
    }

.right-inner-addon {
    position: relative;
}

    .right-inner-addon input {
        padding-right: 30px;
    }

    .right-inner-addon i {
        position: absolute;
        right: 0px;
        padding: 10px 12px;
        pointer-events: none;
    }
```

**asp.net mvc:**

```
<div class="right-inner-addon">
   <i class="icon-search"></i>
    Find by name: @Html.TextBox("SearchString", ViewBag.CurrentFilter as string, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Search" } })
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried my solution? Do you have an answer to your question?

Answer (score 1):

When you want to add an attribute to the control there is no need to write `new { htmlAttributes = ....`. Try:

```
<div class="right-inner-addon">
   <i class="icon-search"></i>
    Find by name: @Html.TextBox("SearchString", ViewBag.CurrentFilter as string, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Search" })
</div>
```

UPDATED.
Here is the correct solution for your problem:
http://jsfiddle.net/Kpblca4/gjdu0t93/

Comment: i have updated my question with print screen, the search icon is showing behind the textbox

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
<div class="right-inner-addon">
   <i class="icon-search"></i>
    Find by name: @Html.TextBox("SearchString", ViewBag.CurrentFilter as string, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Search" })
</div>
```

Note, that only some attributes needs **`@`** character at the begining, like `class`.

Comment: i have updated my question with print screen, the search icon is showing behind the textbox

Comment: mvc project in VS usually have some out of box styles. Check in browser -> F12 what styles ruined your design and just override them.

Comment: I do not see anything that is causing to be search icon not display properly, is that to do with z-index?

Comment: you can try z-index. Your problem definatly css